# Metropolis-Hastings to sample from dependent random variables

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Imagine the goal is sampling from $p(X,Y)$ and X and Y are dependent real-valued random variables, i.e. $p(X|Y)\neq p(X)$. Now the question is how can we apply Metropolis-Hastings algorithm on the problem? Obviously it is not possible any more to apply different proposals for $X$ and $Y$ at each step because of dependency.

Comment: You can still generate proposals in two steps, you just need to use a likelihood that takes bothRV into consideration.